# php get future date time

Tags: php, date, time

I don't know how to explain this correctly but just some sample for you guys so that you can really get what Im trying to say.

Today is April 09, 2010

7 days from now is April 16,2010

Im looking for a php code, which can give me the exact date giving the number of days interval prior to the current date.

I've been looking for a thread which can solve or even give a hint on how to solve this one but I found none.

Comment: Could this possibly be rephrased as "I want to add `$x` number of days to a given date"?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Can you re-specify what are the known parameters and what values you are interested in?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you are using PHP >= 5.2, I strongly suggest you use the new DateTime object, which makes working with dates a lot easier:

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime("2006-12-12");
$date->modify("+7 day");
echo $date->format("Y-m-d");
?>
```

Comment: or for a 1 liner `echo date_create("2006-12-12")->modify("+7 day")->format("Y-m-d");`

Answer (score 14):

Take a look here - http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

```
<?php
// This is what you need for future date from now.
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("+7 day"));

// This is what you need for future date from specific date.
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('01/01/2010 +7 day'));
?>
```

Comment: +1. You may not want to `echo strtotime(...)`. Instead, use the returned value inside the date function, such as `echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-7 days'))`.

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer is not wrong but not the best solution:

The *DateTime* class takes an optional string in the constructor, which can define the same logic as the *modify* method.

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime("+7 day");
```

For example:

```
<?php
namespace DateTimeExample;

$now = new \DateTime("now");
$inOneWeek = new \DateTime("+7 day");

printf("Now it's the %s", $now->format('Y-m-d'));
printf("In one week it's the %s", $inOneWeek->format('Y-m-d'));
```

For a list of available relative formats (for the DateTime constructor) take a look at http://php.net/manual/de/datetime.formats.relative.php

Answer (score 2):

If you are using PHP >= 5.3, this could be an option.

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime( "2006-12-12" );
$date->add( new DateInterval( "P7D" ) );
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to look into [strtotime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). I'd imagine your final code would look something like this:

```
$future_date = "April 16,2010";
$seconds = strtotime($future_date) - time();
$days = $seconds /(60 * 60* 24);
echo $days; //Returns "6.0212962962963"
```

Comment: "6.0212962962963" - classical example of PHP float precision issue :)

Comment: Not really, just the _exact_ number of days represented as a decimal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mktime with date. (http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Date gives you the current date. This is better than simply adding/subtracting to a timestamp since it can take into account daylight savings time.

```
<?php
# this gets you 7 days earlier than the current date
$lastWeek = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")-7, date("Y"));
# now pretty-print it out (eg, prints April 2, 2010.)
echo date("F j, Y.", $lastWeek), "\n";
?>
```