# How can I get 10 days future date from today in Laravel (PHP)

Tags: php, laravel, datetime

I'm trying to get a future date from today using PHP.

like `date('dS M, Y (D)')` returns **21st Jan, 2021 (Thu)** (Today)

How can we get a future date from today!

Comment: Hi Aniket Das, there are many ways to do this; depending on the context by which you want to get this number. You can add intervals, or pick a specific date to format. Read through the manual here, it is immensely informative  https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php and https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php get future date time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2605446/php-get-future-date-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use PHP's DateTime class:

```
    $dt = new DateTime();
    $dt->modify( '+10 days' );
    echo $dt->format( 'dS M, Y (D)' );
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Answer (score 5):

You could use the superb [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) package by installing it via composer.

Then in your code you can run add days like this

**Entering the date piece by piece**

```
$dt = Carbon::create(2021, 1, 22, 0);
echo $dt->addDays(10); // adding 10 days from today on
```

**Using `now()`**

```
echo Carbon::now()->addDays(10); // adding 10 days from today on
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it that way. You don't need any package for this job.

```php
$tenDaysLater = date ('Y-m-d', strtotime ('+10 day'));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$addDay= strtotime($date . "+10 days"); 

echo date('Y-m-d', $addDay);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
$datetime = Carbon::now()->addDays(30);
```